# RavenDB Aggresive caching doesn't seem to do anything different

Tags: performance, caching, ravendb

Inside the following block

```
using (DocumentSession.Advanced.DocumentStore.AggressivelyCacheFor(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))) 
{         
    return session.Query<Camera, Camera_Facets().Where(...).ToFacets("facets/CameraFacets")
}
```

I am executing a query and asking for facets. When I see the call on the raven server console, it takes 2.5 seconds, but when I run the same query again and again, it still takes the exact same time.

Now how is this meant to be fast? when it returns in roughly the exact same time every time. Am I missing something here. I am using build 499, and running client server mode, talking to raven on my local machine.

**note:** i am running the query on my data store for my domain, the camera code above is shown for reference purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faceted queries and aggressive caching currently don't work together. Faceted queries are a new feature and as yet they haven't been made to work with aggressive caching.

**Note** that regular queries work with aggressive caching just fine, it's only faceted queries that have this issue.